# Is it possible to add a photo in a Xamarin Forms cross platform application using only C#?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add a user profile picture in a Xamarin app, but I'm only finding deployments in Xamarin only for Android, is it possible to perform this addition on both platforms?

Comment: Your question is lacking a LOT of detail.  Do you mean assigning an image to an entry in the device Contacts?  Or using an image from the camera or device gallery in your app?  Or something else entirely?

Comment: Hello Jason, I want to use an image from the camera or gallery of devices in my application, but all the items I thought I had were only for android, I would like to know if there is any plugin or open source or nuget that I can use this function in IOS and on Android.

Comment: Sorry for my English, I'm rusty (I haven't used writing for years) and I'm Brazilian

Comment: use [Media Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android)